# No Such File Directoy

Tags: php

Dont know whats the reason behind because my code wont run. Its say's there's no such file directory but there is and index inside a folder. Does my code or the server?Dont know whats the reason behind because my code wont run. Its say's there's no such file directory but there is and index inside a folder. Does my code or the server?

Please see images below. Thanks!.

https://ibb.co/fKqZ5m

https://ibb.co/cDynQm

code:

navbar.php

```
<?php include('tooltip.php'); ?>    

    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </a>

                    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">

                    <ul class="nav">
                    <li class=""><a  rel="tooltip"  data-placement="bottom" title="Home" id="home"   href="index.php"><i class="icon-home icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Home</a> </li>
                    <!-- <li class="divider-vertical"></li> -->
                    <li class="">
                    <a rel="tooltip"  data-placement="bottom" title="Click Here to About" id="login" href="about.php"><i class="icon-info-sign icon-large"></i>&nbsp;About</a> 
                    </li>
                    <li class="">
                    <a rel="tooltip"  data-placement="bottom" title="Click Here to Admin Login" id="login" href="librarian/index.php"><i class="icon-user icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Admin</a>
                    </li>
                    <!--<li class="">
                    <a rel="tooltip"  data-placement="bottom" title="Click Here to Register Member" id="login" href="register_member.php"><i class="icon-user icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Register Member</a>
                    </li>-->
                    </ul>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

index.php inside librarian directory.

```
<?php 
include('header.php'); 
include('navbar.php'); 
?>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="margin-top">
            <div class="row">   
            <div class="span12">
                <div class="login">
                <div class="log_txt">
                <p><strong><center>Login</center></strong></p>
                </div>
                        <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST">
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Username</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <div class="controls">
                                    <button id="login" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn"><i class="icon-signin icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Submit</button>
                                </div>
                                </div>

                                <?php
                                if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
                                session_start();
                                $username = $_POST['username'];
                                $password = $_POST['password'];
                                $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
                                $result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
                                $num_row = mysql_num_rows($result);
                                    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
                                    if( $num_row > 0 ) {
                                        header('location:users.php');
                                $_SESSION['id']=$row['user_id'];
                                    }
                                    else{ ?>
                                <div class="alert alert-danger">Access Denied</div>     
                                <?php
                                }}
                                ?>
                        </form>

                </div>
            </div>      
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: <a rel="tooltip"  data-placement="bottom" title="Click Here to Admin Login" id="login" href="librarian/index.php"><i class="icon-user icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Admin</a>

Comment: done sir.Kindly check it. thanks

Comment: You still haven't provided the directory tree, your problem is mostly just a wrong path.

Comment: this is the direcotry tree. https://ibb.co/fKKuMR

Comment: So, where in that directory is the `navbar.php` located?

Comment: the navbar.php located inside the root directory or inside the htdocs in the server.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `../librarian/index.php` because `navbar.php` is in a different directory *(`youth`)*.

Most likely your tree is like this:

```
htdocs
    - librarian
        - index.php
    - youth
        - navbar.php
```

Using `../` will move you up a directory then you can target `librarian`.

Comment: ahm lets ignore the youth folder because that is in the localhost. Kidly visit this site. ive change my index file inside the librarian directory "../librarian/index.php" in the navbar.php  http://sanjoseyouth.byethost32.com/librarian/index.php its the link in the admin.

Comment: It would be better to edit your question and add the directory tree of both files